# Tips on color in UI?

Tags: color, website-design, interface-design

I've been working on a personal project recently, and I'm having trouble implementing the full color scheme. I've uploaded a semi-functional mockup .

[image]

[image]

[image]

My primary and secondary colors are: rgba(245, 112, 100, 1) and rgba(245, 215, 110, 1). It's a red and a yellow, respectively, and can be seen in limited amounts on the mockup itself (although you have to highlight text to see the yellow).

[image]

I was looking to implement a gradient between these two colors, but I have no idea how to add more of these colors without impacting the usability of the ui.

Comment: There does not appear to be any real attempt to integrate color at your link. You should take a stab at it, then ask about specific areas you are concerned about.

Comment: Check out this question here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15995/given-a-color-scheme-how-do-i-apply-to-website-design/45617#45617 it might help.